# Simulation in java

Tags: java, simulation

I am novice to the simulation world, and want to learn how programmers develop real simulation projects in java. I would use eclipse.
Could anyone point to other things that I need to know (e.g. other packages, software etc. and their purposes)?

I am afraid the question might seem a bit vague as it is not clear which type of project I am talking about. But being a novice, let me say that it's to begin how to code a simulation project.

Answer (score 11):

If you are building a [Monte-Carlo model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) for a [discrete event simulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_event_simulation) or simulation model for [pricing derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_option_model) you should find there is a [body](http://monte-carlo-simulation.qarchive.org/) of [framework](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/research/RG/net_sim/simulation_group/akaroa/about.chtml) [code](http://ptolemy.eecs.berkeley.edu/) already out there.  If you are doing a numerical simulation such as a [finite-element model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) you will be basing your simulation on a [matrix](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/) [computation](http://ressim.berlios.de/) library.  [Other types of simulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_simulation) exist, but these are the two most likely cases.

I've never written a finite element model and know next to nothing about these, although I did have occasion to port one to [DEC Visual FORTRAN](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/site/dspp/menuitem.863c3e4cbcdc3f3515b49c108973a801/?ciid=8508092f62f02110092f62f02110275d6e10RCRD) at one point.  Although the program ([SAFIR,](http://www.argenco.ulg.ac.be/logiciels/SAFIR/downloads-2.html) if anyone cares) was commented in French, the porting exercise consisted of modifying two date functions for a total of 6 lines of FORTRAN code - and writing a makefile.

Monte-Carlo models consist of measuring some base population to get [distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) of one or more variables of interest.  Then you take a [Pseudo-Random number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) with good [statistical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#Post-processing_and_statistical_checks) and [geometric](http://random.mat.sbg.ac.at/~charly/server/node3.html) properties (the [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) algorithm is widely used for this) and write a [function](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/cache/ITY_PUBLIC/NTTS2001/46.pdf) to convert the output of this to a [random variable with the appropriate distribution.](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)  You will probably be able to find [library](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) [functions](http://warp.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/Software/SimKit/Documentation/Utility/RandomNumber.html) that do this unless your variables have a really unusual distribution.

Then you build or obtain a simulation framework and write a routine that takes the random variables and does whatever computation you want to do for the model.  You run it, storing the results of each simulation, until the error is within some desired tolerance level.  After that, you calculate statistics (means, distributions etc.) from all of the runs of the simulation model.

There are quite a lot of resources on the web, and many books on simulation modelling, particularly in the area of derivatives pricing.  You should hunt around and see what you can find.

As an aside, the [`random`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html) module on [Python](http://www.python.org) has conversion functions for quite a few distributions.  If you want one you could get that and port the appropriate conversion function to java.  You could use the output of the python one with the same random number seed to test the correctness of the java one.

Answer (score 8):

Discrete-event simulation is a good option for problems that can be modeled as individual events that take place at specific times. Key activities are:

- randomly generating times and durations based on empirical data, and
- accumulating statistics as the simulation runs.

For example, you could simulate the activity in a parking garage as the entries and departures of a cars and the loss of customers who can't enter because the garage is full. This can be done with two model classes, a Car and the Garage, and three infrastructure classes, an Event class (described below), a Schedule to manage events, and a Monitor to accumulate data.

Here's a brief sketch of how it could work.

### Event

An Event has a time, and represents calling a specific method on an object of a specific class.

### Schedule

The Schedule keeps a queue of Events, ordered by Event time. The Schedule drives the overall simulation with a simple loop. As long as there are remaining Events (or until the Event that marks the end of the simulation run):

1. take the earliest Event from the queue,
2. set the "world clock" to the time of that event, and
3. invoke whatever action the Event specifies.

### Car

The Car class holds the inter-arrival and length-of-stay statistics.

When a Car arrives, it:

1. logs its arrival with the Monitor,
2. consults the world clock, determines how long before the next Car should arrive, and  posts that arrival Event on the Schedule.
3. asks the Garage whether it is full:

   1. if full, the Car logs its departure as a lost customer with the Monitor.
   2. if not full, the Car:

      1. logs its entry with the Monitor,
      2. tells the Garage it has entered (so that the Garage can decrease its available capacity),
      3. determines how long it will stay, and posts its departure Event with the Schedule.

When a Car departs, it:

1. tells the Garage (so the Garage can increase available capacity), and
2. logs its departure with the Monitor.

### Garage

The Garage keeps track of the Cars that are currently inside, and knows about its available capacity.

### Monitor

The Monitor keeps track of the statistics in which you're interested: number of customers (successfully-arriving Cars), number of lost customers (who arrived when the lot was full), average length of stay, revenue (based on rate charged for parking), etc.

### A simulation run

Start the simulation by putting two Events into the schedule:

1. the arrival of the first Car (modeled by instantiating a Car object and calling its "arrive" event) and
2. the end of the simulation.

Repeat the basic simulation loop until the end-of-simulation event is encountered. At that point, ask the Garage to report on its current occupants, and ask the Monitor to report the overall statistics for the session.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it **depends**.

Unless you can make the question more specific, there is no way to give an answer.

What do you want to simulate?

For example, if you want to simulate adding two numbers, you can do it using something like:

```
a = b + c;
```

If you want to simulate the bouncing of a ball, you can do that using a little bit of math equations and the graphic libraries.

If you want to simulate a web browser, you can do that too.

So the exact answer depends on what simulation you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Come up with a problem first.

There's no such things as a generic "simulation".  There are lots of techniques out there.

If you're just a gamer who wants to have pseudo-physics, maybe something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159059472X) would be what you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Repast Symphony: http://repast.sourceforge.net/repast_simphony.html

"Repast Simphony 2.0 Beta, released on 12/3/2010, is a tightly integrated, richly interactive, cross platform Java-based modeling system that runs under Microsoft Windows, Apple Mac OS X, and Linux. It supports the development of extremely flexible models of interacting agents for use on workstations and small computing clusters.

Repast Simphony models can be developed in several different forms including the ReLogo
 dialect of Logo, point-and-click flowcharts, Groovy, or Java, all of which can be fluidly interleaved NetLogo
 models can also be imported.

Repast Simphony has been successfully used in many application domains including social science, consumer products, supply chains, possible future hydrogen infrastructures
, and ancient pedestrian traffico name a few."

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but for Simulation in Java I just installed and tested JavaSim by 
Mark Little, University of Newcastle upon Tyne. As far as I can tell, it works very well if you have a model you can convert into a discrete event simulation.  See Mark's site http://markclittle.blogspot.com.au/2008/03/csimjavasim.html. I also attempted to use Desmo-J, which is very extensive and has a 2-D graphical mode, but could not get it going under JDK 1.6 on a Mac.

Comment: Just an update: my problems getting Desmo-J going were related (I suspect) to other copies of simulation libraries on the classpath, with inevitable name clashes. Desmo-J should work in a clean environment.